# how to loop over vector elements in R with foreach

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, foreach

I am relatively new to R and cannot figure out how to turn my `for` loop into a `foreach` loop.

I have a vector of few elements, i.e.

```
> hpattern
[1] "sim0_pmax.tif" "sim0_vmax.tif" "sim1_pmax.tif" "sim1_vmax.tif"
> typeof(hpattern)
[1] "character"
```

First: I come from the python word, the `hpattern` item should be a list, since it is created as follows

```
list_h30 = data.frame(list.files(path = tr30dir, pattern=paste(depthfile,".+$",sep=""), recursive = TRUE, full.names = FALSE))
hpattern <- sub(paste(".*",depthfile,sep=""), "", list_h30[,1])
```

How come the `typeof` `hpattern` is character and not list?

Second: if I run

```
for (hpi in hpattern) {print(hpi)}
```

I get

```
[1] "sim0_pmax.tif"
[1] "sim0_vmax.tif"
[1] "sim1_pmax.tif"
[1] "sim1_vmax.tif"
```

if I run

```
foreach(hpi=hpattern, .combine='c') %do% {print(hpi)}
```

I get

```
[1] "sim0_pmax.tif"
[1] "sim0_vmax.tif"
[1] "sim1_pmax.tif"
[1] "sim1_vmax.tif"
[1] "sim0_pmax.tif" "sim0_vmax.tif" "sim1_pmax.tif" "sim1_vmax.tif"
```

I do not understand why I get the last output.

Comment: 1. Why do you expect a list? `sub` always returns a character vector. 2. You should learn `lapply` loops befor you learn `foreach` loops. If you understand `lapply`, which is a often-used base R function, it will be much easier to understand `foreach` loops. The last output line is the return value of the `foreach` loop. Avoid using `print` like in your examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Roland said, `sub` returns a character vector (in `R`, most things are vectors). Another useful function to check your object is `str`.

About `foreach`: it combines the output of each execution of the loop. You've specified that you want a vector (by `.combine = 'c'`).

As `print` returns every object invisibly, each `hpi` gets printed inside the loop and then combined to the final vector. Compare it to when you don't print it:

```
foreach(hpi=hpattern, .combine='c') %do% {hpi}
[1] "sim0_pmax.tif" "sim0_vmax.tif" "sim1_pmax.tif" "sim1_vmax.tif"
```

Comment: thanks to both you and Roland for the answers, I will for sure take a look at lapply to better understand foreach